# Fowler Distance in Solovay-Kitaev Algorithm

Tags: quantum-gate, universal-gates, solovay-kitaev-algorithm

I have been using [this code](https://github.com/cryptogoth/skc-python) to implement the Solovay-Kitaev algorithm for approximating arbitrary single qubit gates. One measure of success it gives is the 'Fowler distance'. I cant find a definition for the Fowler distance anywhere, and am wondering how it relates to the approximation error 'epsilon' used in proofs of the SK theorem (such as in Appendix 3 of Nielsen&Chuang). Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to QCSE! [This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.3348) defines Fowler distance of two single-qubit gates as $\sqrt{\frac{2 - |\mathrm{tr}(U_1U_2^\dagger)|}{2}}$, see eq $(1)$ on p.2. Is this what you have in mind?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that seems to be what I'm looking for. I also found it in a paper by Fowler yesterday after posting the question. Thanks again!